# Send Ping towards a Public-IP for HealthCheck using AWS Lambda Function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm going to setup a Health-Check towards a Public-IP.
I do not want to use Route53-HealthCheck because it pings every 2-3 seconds. 
I'm gonna send ping every 5-10 minutes to that IP.So I've decided to use AWS Lambda function. However I read here that Ping is not open on Lambda: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=263968

Is there any AWS services that I can use it for this case?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe something like https://github.com/apaszke/tcp-ping.

Comment: https://read.acloud.guru/how-to-keep-your-lambda-functions-warm-9d7e1aa6e2f0

Comment: Health Check have the default frequency of 30 seconds, and you can lower the number of regions to reduce the overall request count.